# Low Battery Performance on Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, battery, charging

I have recently installed Kubuntu 15.10 on my Lenovo G50-70. But the pain is that it is giving extremely poor battery life.
After full charging it to 100% it only gives me 45 minutes of battery backup on my 8-10 months old Laptop.

Previously I had Windows 10 and it easily gave 3+ hours of battery backup.

Also when the battery is critically low it does give any warning message but shuts the laptop at 5%!

Please suggest ways to improve battery performance. Screenshot below:

[image: Low Battery Performance on Kubuntu image]

Answer (score 2):

You should see if your cpu usage is not too high. Try to install `tlp` with:

```
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

Lower your brightness and turn off Bluetooth.

TIP: to turn on tlp, use:

```
sudo -i
```

that'll change your current user to root. Then turn it on by typing:

```
tlp start
```